# How to make different materials for different objects?

Tags: materials

When I change one material, it changes it on another object. Why and how do I fix it? is there some link between the objects?

[image: M]

Here is my blender file of Iron Man's faceplate.

Here is my whole screen with the main portion of the face selected. On the right, you can see the material, and I can tell you that that is the same as the eyes part:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, you are sharing the material on several meshes. See below. If so, click the highlighted box to create a new instance.... and adding custom names helps keep track of what mesh should carry which material.
[image]

After clicking... name it something easy to recognize

[image]

Comment: No sweat... StackExchange is a great community for Blender stuff... welcome.